# insert select ignore some subquery returned values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do an insert select but require some aliased values for calculations but don't need all of them for my insert. I just need field0, total_sum, hard_coded_val but rely on the others for the calculations.

is there any way to either ignore the other values or specify the VALUES() in the insert SELECT?

```
INSERT INTO table(field0,total_sum,hard_coded_val) 
  SELECT s.*, sum1+sum2 AS total_sum, 'hard_coded_val' FROM 
 (SELECT t.*, (fielda+fieldb)*2 AS sum1, (fieldc+fieldd)/4 AS sum2 from
 (SELECT field0, 
    sum(IF(field1 = 1, totalcount,0)) AS fielda,
    sum(IF(field1 = 2, totalcount,0)) AS fieldb,
    sum(IF(field1 = 3, totalcount,0)) AS fieldc,
    sum(IF(field1 = 4,totalcount,0)) AS fieldd 
  from source_table GROUP BY field0) 
    t ORDER BY sum1 DESC) 
      s ORDER BY total_sum DESC
```

Comment: Replace `s.*` with `s.field0`

Comment: Brilliant please add as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to limit the number of columns you're returning. `*` will return all columns for the table associated with it.

```
INSERT INTO table(field0,total_sum,hard_coded_val) 
  SELECT s.field0, sum1+sum2 AS total_sum, 'hard_coded_val' FROM
...
```